# Expand / Collapse textarea while typing and adjust rows count

Tags: javascript, textarea

Ok so the goal i am trying to achiev is this:

- create `textarea` field that has only 1 `row` and as you hit `enter` it expands for user by one more row
- when user remove text content from line it removes extra row

So far i have this code: https://jsfiddle.net/kmo9x3qt/

```
document.querySelector('textarea').onkeydown = function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        this.setAttribute('rows', parseInt(this.getAttribute('rows')) + 1);
    }
};
```

Very simple idea how to make it to auto expand. What i am struggling with is how to detect (while user hits `backspace`) if he removed last content from last line so i can collapse row.

I saw some topics on stack using some content measuring code but i dont want to do it, this method seems more "stable".

Comment: How will you differ between pressing backspace once to remove one letter and pressing backspace once to remove an entire chunk of selected text? Hence people count the content length.

Comment: This is one of the things that look very simple for a human being, but are hard or almost impossible to implement. I agree with @Shilly, that you can't detect what and how much has been deleted by a single backspace press. And what if the users don't press enter at all?

Comment: For textareas, I opted to forget about making the area smaller again and just add another row once the amount of letters exceeds some factor of font-size * textarea width % . For fields that absolutely need to scale smaller again, I just use a div with content editable and style it to look like a textarea instead, so that it will always become bigger / smaller due to being a block level element.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `scrollHeight`

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').onkeydown = function(e) {

    if(e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 8) {
        this.style.height='0px'
        this.style.height = this.scrollHeight+'px'
    }
};
```

```css
textarea {
    width:300px;
    resize:none;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    padding:10px;
    background:#dfddde;
    color:#373737;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="1"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get number of lines using this snippet:

```
var lines = document.querySelector('textarea').value.split("\n").length;
```

---

And the whole code might look like this:

```js
    document.querySelector('textarea').onkeyup = function(e) {
      // this is for the Return key
      if(e.keyCode === 13) {
            this.setAttribute('rows', parseInt(this.getAttribute('rows')) + 1);
      }
      // and for the Backspace key
      if(e.keyCode === 8) {
        var lines = this.value.split("\n").length;  
        if(this.getAttribute('rows') !== lines) {
            this.setAttribute('rows', lines);
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<textarea rows="1"></textarea>
```

Comment: hmmm it only expands by 1 row and then it just adds scroll to content and removing rows doesnt work at all

Comment: Updated the answer, see codepen for code reference and working example